# getting a list of checkbox Ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a string of IDs for a group of checkboxes.  The code below does contain the IDs, but it also contains blank spaces and double commas for checkboxes that are not checked.

Is there a way to get a string of just the IDs?

Thanks!

```
$($('input[type=checkbox][name=selector]')).each(function () {
       var sThisVal = (this.checked ? this.id : "");
       sList += (sList == "" ? sThisVal : "," + sThisVal);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to get comma separated ids of checked checkboxes

```
strIds = $('input[type=checkbox][name=selector]').map(function () {                        
      if(this.checked) return  this.id;    
}).get().join(',');
```

*Making it little simple by simplifying selector and making selector to return on checked checkboxes using [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).*

```
strIds = $('[name=selector]:checked').map(function () {                        
       return  this.id;    
}).get().join(',');
```

Comment: I have multiple checkboxes, so I need to use .each to loop through all of them - thanks